# Laravel ORM getting result as object array

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have two simple problems in my laravel project

1.**ORM getting result as objects**

Here is my query to get details that matches an email

```
$users =User::where('user_email',$request->email)->first()->toArray();
```

Now i will get the result as array,but i need the result as objects.

eg: i need to read `echo $users->user_email;`

2.**Named routes didn't worked**

In my routes file i've this

```
Route::post('login',['as'=>'validatelogin','uses'=>'LoginController@login']);
```

And in my view

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url('validatelogin') }}" method="post">
```

But i will get methodnotfound exception

Laravel version:5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `->toArray()` part from the query. This method converts collection or object to an array.
2. Use `{{ route('validatelogin') }}` instead of `url()` helper. To check if route has name run `php artisan route:list` command.

Comment: Yeah its worked ,one more question when i check the page source i will see the action url as  `http://localhost:8001/login` how can i make this as only `\login`

Comment: All Laravel helpers will create full URL. You can create URLs manually, like `<form role="form" action="/login" method="post">`

Comment: Getting notfoundexception when i try this `action="/validatelogin"`

Comment: My bad. Change it to `/login`, `validatelogin` is a route name. :) I've edited my previous comment. It'll work if you have `login` route with GET method.